# Выделение памяти под двумерный массив в структуре

Tags: c

```
struct man {
    char **tel;
};
void main()
{
    int n = 5, m = 5, l = 20;
    man *bot = new man[n];

    bot->tel = new char *[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    bot->tel[i] = new char[l];
}
```

Comment: Эээ, а в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: так не работает

Comment: Не работает, в смысле не компилится?

Ей void main() не нравится. Напишите

    int main () 

и странслируется. Это про код, который мы *видим*.

Comment: Мы не видим самого главного - сообщенй об ошибках :) void main() это может и warning. А вот если в тегах стоит "C", а в исходнике new, то ой :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
man *bot=new man[n];
```

этой строчкой ты создаешь массив структур, а обращаешся как к одной обычной структуре.

тогда код ваш должен быть чем то типо этого.

```
struct man
{
    char **tel;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 5, m = 5, l = 20;

    man *bot = new man[n];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < n; ii++)
    {
        bot[ii]->tel = new char*[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            bot[ii]->tel[i] = new char[l];
    }
}
```

ну а если не хотите массив структур то просто измените строку

```
man *bot=new man[n];
```

на

```
man *bot = new man;
```

Answer (score 1):

Честно, несколько раз бился с указателем на указатель, удалось оживить код только однажды, и совершенно не понятным образом. Т.ч. совет лично от меня, любой многомерный массив можно свернуть в одномерный. Одно условие, размерность массива задаётся только при его создании.

Comment: @Qway, тренируйтесь упорнее. 

А для чего Вам еще С/C++, как не для возни с кусочками памяти, заполненными разными битиками?

Comment: На самом деле, указатель на указатель - это просто. Надо просто всю эту структуру в виде картинки представить.